# how can i install php 5.35 using apt

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt

i tried:

```
apt-cache policy php5-dev
```

and got

```
Candidate: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7
```

How can i get the latest stable version (5.35) using apt, i understand i need to add a repository to my sources but how do i find one?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the [Dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) repository, which has PHP 5.3.5 packaged. [Here is how](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/).

I just noticed you use Ubuntu. Those repositories are designed for Debian but many users report success using them with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu as debian stores all packages into a pool, so you can just search for php in the ubuntu packages, right now for natty you have 5.3.3 (http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/php5-common)

Another way would be to build your own deb package, you can start doing so by downloading the packages you see on the natty release and play with `dpkg-buildpackage`